# Exception and smarty

Tags: php, exception, smarty, smarty3

I have block try - catch and i want assign error to the template to $error. I tried:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
   $smarty->assign("error", 'Error! Details: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Also tried:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
   $error = $e->getMessage());
}
$smarty->assign("error", $error);
```

But when there is no error, smarty requires this variable and all crashes. Is there any way to deal with it without using if? Or may be i am doing wrong from the begining?

Comment: it is upper -  the problem is how to attach error to smarty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do a

```
{$error|default:''}
```

You don't need an `{if}{/if}` for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Php:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
   $smarty->assign("error", true);
   $smarty->assign("error_message", $e->getMessage());
}
```

Smarty:

```
{if $error}
       {$error_message}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having the template check if the $error variable is defined?

```
{if !empty($error)}
  Oops: {$error}
{/if}
```

otherwise you can re-assign variables:

```
$smarty->assign("error", null);
try {
  // …
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $smarty->assign("error", $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: which of the above did you try?